# How can I disable clicking in a FMX Form?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

For an Application I need the user to be disabled to click on a specific window, while he is still able to use a window, which is in front of the other window.
In Delphi, this works perfectly fine with

```
ExampleForm.Enabled:= False;
```

but in Firemonkey it seems as if the enabled property does'n exist anymore. As well, it would be really helpful if it could disable the keyboard inputs etc. as well. I would really appreciate a solution for that problem, thanks for your time!

PS: I use the Delphi 10.3 Version

Comment: The FMX equivalent is `HitTest` if I recall.

Comment: @jerry dogde So i can simply disable the HitTest property of the window?

Comment: It's a bit more than that. It works differently. You'll need to study it and make sure it fits your exact requirements.

Comment: @jerry dogde According to http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.HitTest it should work for the biggest part, but i think it wouldn't disable keyboard inputs, right?

Comment: But @Dirty, you did not mention keyboard input at all in your question!

Comment: @Tom Brunberg Thats right, Hittest might already solve the problem, but it would be helpful if i wouldn't need to disable the keyboard input manually

Comment: Then you need to edit your question! All requirements must be expressed in the question itself, and not added here to the comments where they are easily overlooked.

Comment: Thanks, @Tom Brunberg, i will edit it

Comment: @JerryDodge I just tried the HitTest property, but it doesn't seem to exist for forms themself - sadly you can just disable single objects with it

Answer (score 2):

In Firemonkey, you're typically expected to implement all of your controls inside of a `TLayout` or one of its descendants such as `TGridLayout`. As long as all of your controls are in there, you can disable its `Enabled` property. The form is really just a container and not the same type of control in FMX as it is in VCL.